# Convert an integer to BYTE value

Tags: c++, serial-port

I'm trying to write some command to serial comm port. Say I need to send 10 bytes of data to comm port. Now out of that 10 bytes, data message is something like:

```
Byte offset 0    - message id
Byte offset 1-4  - unix time in format 1432419028
Byte offset 5-10 - data
```

My query is how do I convert unix time 1432419028 to fit in my BYTE array. 
Platform is C++ Visual Studio.

I got some sample to write like

```
  BYTE initmsg[10];
  unsigned int* UNALIGNED epoch_time = (unsigned int*) &initmsg[1];
  *epoch_time = 12345678;
```

But I would like to construct the initmsg look like below.

```
  initmsg[1] = 0x01;
  initmsg[2] = 0x01;
  initmsg[3] = 0x01;
  initmsg[4] = 0x01;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper portable way would be, in Big-Endian:

```
uint32_t time = ...;
initmsg[1] = (time >> 24) & 0xFF;
initmsg[2] = (time >> 16) & 0xFF;
initmsg[3] = (time >> 8) & 0xFF;
initmsg[4] = time & 0xFF;
```

And in Little-Endian:

```
uint32_t time = ...;
initmsg[1] = time & 0xFF;
initmsg[2] = (time >> 8) & 0xFF;
initmsg[3] = (time >> 16) & 0xFF;
initmsg[4] = (time >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

What endianness to use is not related to the architecture in use, but should be specified in the documentation. If it is not, well, trial and error...

**UPDATE**: Why is that? You have to look at the bits, for example one of the middle bytes:

```
       31            24              16               8               0
time:
        X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X

time >> 16:
        > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X

(time >> 16) & 0xFF:
 0xFF = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
      & > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X
      = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X X X X X X X X
```

That is, you shift the bits to put the ones you want in bit positions 0-7, and then do a binary AND with 0xFF to zero out any other bit except 0-7. Naturally, you are truncating to a byte when assigning to the array, so this last step is not strictly necessary, but I find a good practice to explicitly do the `& 0xFF`.

It is also useful to think in hexadecimal:

```
1432419028 = 0x5560FAD4

0x5560FAD4 >> 24 = 0x55
0x5560FAD4 >> 16 = 0x5560
0x5560FAD4 >>  8 = 0x5560FA
0x5560FAD4 >>  0 = 0x5560FAD4

(0x5560FAD4 >> 24) & 0xFF = 0x55
(0x5560FAD4 >> 16) & 0xFF = 0x60
(0x5560FAD4 >>  8) & 0xFF = 0xFA
(0x5560FAD4 >>  0) & 0xFF = 0xD4
```

Comment: Well, Im working for ARM processor, so Little-Endian would be fine for me. But could you please explain a bit more about this bit shifting to right?

Comment: @hypheni: ARM CPUs can boot into both little-endian and big-endian. Which one will be in effect is decided at boot time.

Comment: @hypheni: Here, I've added a few schemas. About endianness, the architecture is (should be) irrelevant, as both sides of the communication should be using architecture independent code to manage it. The endianness of a protocol must be specified in the protocol documentation.

Comment: @rodrigo: How about memcpy? memcpy(byteBuffer, &intValue, sizeof(int)).

Comment: @hypheni: The `memcpy(buffer + 1, &intValue, sizeof(int))` will work, and it is better than the `UNALIGNED` hack. But it is not portable in the sense that you dump the internal `int` representation. If it is an internal communication, between the program and itself, no big deal. But if you are sending the bytes through a serial port, then you should be able to tell exactly what you are sending.